# .htaccess redirect url without trailing slashes

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

In my htaccess I have some rewrited urls like these:

```
RewriteRule ^first-page$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^second-page$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^third-page$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=161 [QSA,L]
```

So the final result is: `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page`

Now I would like to turn this into `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page/`

Without the `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page` giving a 404 error.

I tried this code after the url rewrites, but did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either

```
RewriteRule ^first-page/$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^second-page/$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^third-page/$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=161 [QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^first-page /subdir/page.php?id_page=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^second-page /subdir/page.php?id_page=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^third-page /subdir/page.php?id_page=161 [QSA,L]
```

The `$` character tells Apache that this is the end of string and no more characters are expected. So you'll have to notify it to accept the slash at the end of the string, or to just be ready for any extra characters. You can use the `?` flag to make the trailing slash not required, but accepted if present, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^first-page(/)?$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=1 [QSA,L]
```

So this won't let any other characters other than slash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man! Adding (/)? at the end of the url solved the problem. However the preferred url is still the one without the slash. Could you please be so kind to tell me what could I do in order to make the URL with the slash as preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^first-page($|/$) /subdir/page.php?id_page=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^second-page($|/$) /subdir/page.php?id_page=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^third-page($|/$) /subdir/page.php?id_page=161 [QSA,L]
```

($|/$) - It allows both `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page` and `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page/`. It also ensures to not allow any unwanted urls like `www.mywebsite.com/subdir/first-page/some-unwanted-text`.

If you want the url with any parameters you could use as follows

```
RewriteRule ^third-page/?$ /subdir/page.php?id_page=161 [QSA,L]
```